# Number format with Eval in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, eval

I would like to format this kind of number:

1234567.99 (obviously all thousands digits are optional)

In this way: 1.234.567,99

I know it is possible with Eval, but I didn't find an useful guide to do this.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: this what you're looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [overload of Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes three parameters (the link also contains a sample):

- Container
- Expression
- Format

For the format, you'd specify "{0:c}" or whatever format you like. For a list of the Standard Numeric Format Strings, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you want to specify your format with a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g. use "{0:#,##0.00}".

Comment: That's working fine! But, how to set commas for decimals separator and dots for thousands/millions etc. separator?

Comment: @s.milziadi: This depends on the Culture that is set for the thread. If you need to have a consistent culture for the website, you could set it in web.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ToString() extension

```
var value = 1234567.99;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

Or by stating your culture

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE")));
```